# Reset Drupal 7 Site: NIDs, Revision VIDs, Taxonomy Term and Categories, etc

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there a way to keep an entire Drupal 7 site intact, excluding content?

Basically after creating a test environment with many nodes, terms, revisions, etc, I would love to be able to delete all the content/taxonomy and have the IDs reset as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Delete all](https://drupal.org/project/delete_all) module does what you want :)

> This module is used to delete all content and/or users from a site.
>   This is mainly a developer tool, which can come in handy in several
>   cases, listed below.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the quick reply. I can't believe I wasn't aware of this module!